# Remove the "href " for parent element

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a dropdown menu and I want in mobile version to disable  "parent li " link
THe html structure

```
<ul>
<li class="parent"></li>
<li class="parent"></li>
<li class="parent"></li>
<li class="parent">
  <ul class="drop">
     <li class="back">Back</li>//toggle the .drop
     <li class="child"></li>
     <li class="child"></li>
  </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

Every "li" have href link.I want to disable the link just from li.parent..
I try two methods in jquery :

```
$('li.parent').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.drop').show();
}) 
$('back').click(function(){
    $('.drop').hide();
})
```

//this will stop every link from the parent "ul" even the links from "ul.drop".
The links from ul.drom must work.

And I have another problem.If I click on first li ,the dropdown appear,after that if I click another li the collapse will not work .Can anyone help me?

Comment: You missed dot before 'back'

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of wrong things, functional wise and syntax wise identified in your code. Please ignore that and use the following.

Try,

```
 $('li.parent').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('ul.drop').show();
 }); 

 $('.back').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.drop').hide();
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hPBLV/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing '**.**' before 'back'.

```
$('li.parent').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('ul.drop').show();
}) 
$('.back').click(function(){
$('.drop').hide();
})
```